# Vertex doesn't move correctly while in "normal" transform orientation

Tags: transforms, vertices

I've had a re-occurring issue. When a vertex is selected, and the transform orientation is set to "Normal", the vertex does not move in the same direction that the transform manipulator is oriented.

Blender file:[image]

To see what I mean:

1. Open up the file.
2. Select the vertex (it is added to the vertex group in the file)
3. Select Normal transform orientation
4. Grab the green y-axis and move the vertex.
5. Notice the vertex does not move in the direction of the displayed green arrow.

Is this an issue or am I doing something wrong?
I am using latest version of Blender.

Comment: Yeah, I get the same behavior. When I make vertex normals visible I can see the axis it transforms along, this is also the axis it transforms along when I press G,Z,Z (so the positive Z). It would seem that it is transforming correctly, but the 3D manipulator widget is displaying incorrect axes.